# SQL Server 2012+ : Merge elements by time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have been struggling for a while now with that problem and I need some help.
I have the following query :

```
CREATE TABLE Example(
Start NVARCHAR(8),
Endd NVARCHAR(8),
Col1 NVARCHAR(2),
Col2 NVARCHAR(2));

INSERT into Example (Start,Endd,Col1,Col2)
VALUES ('20130801','20140316','02','01'),
('20140317','20140319','04','02'),
('20140320','20140320','04','02'),
('20140321','20140421','02','Z8'),
('20140422','20140429','02','Z9'),
('20140430','20140902','04','02'),
('20140903','20150201','04','02'),
('20150202','20150223','04','02'),
('20150224','20150527','04','02'),
('20150528','99991231','04','02')
;

select MIN(Start)AS Start,MAX(Endd) AS Endd,Col1,Col2 from 
(
    SELECT top (100000000) Start, Endd,Col1, Col2,dense_rank() over(partition by Col1, Col2 order by Start,Endd) as rank 
    ,LEAD (Col1) OVER (order by Start,Endd DESC) as l1
    ,LEAD (Col2) OVER (order by Start,Endd DESC) as l2
    ,LAG (Col1) OVER (order by Start,Endd DESC) as l11
    ,LAG (Col2) OVER (order by Start,Endd DESC) as l22
    FROM Example sp   
    order by Start,Endd
)rq
GROUP BY Col1,Col2,case when (rq.l1=Col1 and rq.l2=Col2) or (rq.l11=Col1 and rq.l22=Col2)  then 0 else rank end
order by Start,Endd;
```

My goal is to merge those data to have the following result:

[image]

However as you can see in the query result, when i have the same values for Col1 and Col2 on different time periods, the merge is not done correctly. It basically tries to merge them all in one, which create issues in the value for the new period.

Would someone be able to help me?

Comment: You need to post the query.

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question to include the relevant table DDL + DML for sample data, as well as your query, as text.

Comment: Sorry for that, first time posting :) I have made some modifications, with a link to the query itself. Hopefully it will be easier for you!

Answer (score 0):

You were getting close in your query and you may have found a solution by now. This is a classic Islands and Gaps problem. I am giving the longer version with no use of `LEAD` AND `LAG`. You can replace perhaps 45% of the code below by using those windowing functions with perhaps a dense rank.

```
DECLARE  @Example TABLE(
Start NVARCHAR(8),
Endd NVARCHAR(8),
Col1 NVARCHAR(2),
Col2 NVARCHAR(2));

INSERT into @Example (Start,Endd,Col1,Col2)
VALUES ('20130801','20140316','02','01'),
('20140317','20140319','04','02'),
('20140320','20140320','04','02'),
('20140321','20140421','02','Z8'),
('20140422','20140429','02','Z9'),
('20140430','20140902','04','02'),
('20140903','20150201','04','02'),
('20150202','20150223','04','02'),
('20150224','20150527','04','02'),
('20150528','99991231','04','02')

SELECT
    TableID=MAX(TableID),Col1=MAX(Col1),Col2=MAX(Col2),Start=MIN(Start),Endd=MAX(Endd)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TableID,Col1,Col2,Start,Endd,ChangeID=MAX(ChangeOnlyTableID) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            AllRecords.TableID,AllRecords.Col1,AllRecords.Col2,AllRecords.Start,AllRecords.Endd,ChangeOnlyTableID=ChangesOnly.TableID
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    This.Start,This.Endd,This.TableID,This.Col1,This.Col2,
                    Changed=CASE WHEN (Next.Col1=This.Col1 AND Next.Col2=This.Col2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                FROM
                ( 
                    SELECT TableID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start,Endd,Col1,Col2),Start,Endd,Col1,Col2 FROM @Example 
                )AS This
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT TableID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start,Endd,Col1,Col2),Start,Endd,Col1,Col2 FROM @Example 
                )
                AS Next ON This.TableID=Next.TableID+1
            )
            AS ChangeMarkers
            WHERE Changed=1
        )
        AS AllRecords
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    This.Start,This.Endd,This.TableID,This.Col1,This.Col2,
                    Changed=CASE WHEN (Next.Col1=This.Col1 AND Next.Col2=This.Col2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT TableID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start,Endd,Col1,Col2),Start,Endd,Col1,Col2 FROM @Example 
                    ) AS This
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT TableID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start,Endd,Col1,Col2),Start,Endd,Col1,Col2 FROM @Example 
                    ) AS Next ON This.TableID=Next.TableID+1
            )
            AS ChangeMarkers
                WHERE Changed=1
        ) 
        AS ChangesOnly ON ChangesOnly.Col1=AllRecords.Col1 AND ChangesOnly.Col2=AllRecords.Col2 AND ChangesOnly.TableID<=AllRecords.TableID
    )AS JoinedResults
    GROUP BY
        TableID,Col1,Col2,Start,Endd
)
AS Final 
GROUP BY 
    Col1,Col2,ChangeID
ORDER BY
    MAX(TableID)
```

You may choose to shorten this somewhat with a few CTE's to produce a query such as:

```
;WITH TableWithIDs AS
( 
    SELECT TableID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start,Endd,Col1,Col2),Start,Endd,Col1,Col2 FROM @Example 
)
,ChangeMarkers AS
(
    SELECT
        This.Start,This.Endd,This.TableID,This.Col1,This.Col2,
        Changed=CASE WHEN (Next.Col1=This.Col1 AND Next.Col2=This.Col2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM
        TableWithIDs AS This
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TableWithIDs AS Next ON This.TableID=Next.TableID+1
)
,ChangesOnly AS
(
    SELECT * FROM ChangeMarkers WHERE Changed=1
)
,
JoinedResults AS
(
    SELECT
        AllRecords.TableID,AllRecords.Col1,AllRecords.Col2,AllRecords.Start,AllRecords.Endd,ChangeOnlyTableID=ChangesOnly.TableID
    FROM
        ChangeMarkers AllRecords
        INNER JOIN ChangesOnly ON ChangesOnly.Col1=AllRecords.Col1 AND ChangesOnly.Col2=AllRecords.Col2 AND ChangesOnly.TableID<=AllRecords.TableID
)

SELECT
    TableID=MAX(TableID),Col1=MAX(Col1),Col2=MAX(Col2),Start=MIN(Start),Endd=MAX(Endd)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TableID,Col1,Col2,Start,Endd,ChangeID=MAX(ChangeOnlyTableID) 
    FROM 
        JoinedResults
    GROUP BY
        TableID,Col1,Col2,Start,Endd
)
AS Final 
GROUP BY 
    Col1,Col2,ChangeID
ORDER BY
    MAX(TableID)
```

There are also some clever hacks that can be applied further using virtual keys however I went the most direct but more verbose route. You should be able to improve on this using a `DENSE_RANK()` with `LEAD()` OR `LAG()`

Comment: Thanks for this :) I will test this and come back. Althought i'm not so skilled so far to replace your code with those leads and lags functions, i'll try to have a look. Maybe a few keys on where to do it?